# Heatmap.js in expo react native application

Tags: react-native, heatmap, expo

Looking into using a heatmap with my react native application using the expo sdk- really do not wish to detach the app from expo, so i was wondering if there was a way to get heatmap.js into my application without linking library to xcode?

I've seen this, and get the approach of creating a webview to display the heatmap in but you still need to link heatmap.min.js to xcode bundle

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: didn't need the heat map in the app after all so no, no answer